# How do I calculate my distance from where I am now to a specific point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

On my app, I have pin pointed an area on interest. And also the GPS of my location, how would I now let the app calculate and show the user how far the distance away is for them?

My .h file is setup with a map view, a button for finding my location and set map options to choose between map/satellite and hybrid views.

In my .m file I have all the code setting the location and where I am, and also enabled tracking mode. Also setup the different map views and have set a pin point on my map and set the latitude and longitude, then enable Zoom & Scroll function. I have also set so that on the map, when you click on the pinpointed area it says the name and a small description of the place. So everything works fine at this point :D

I really need to find how to find the distance between my point and the pinpointed area.

### *please note I am using MapKit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here if you use bellow code in delegate method of CLLocationManager then its return the distance from your current point to destination point..

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    CLLocation *appleHQ = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.322998 longitude:-122.032182];////here put your destination point

    NSLog(@"New Location:%@", newLocation);
    CLLocationDistance distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:appleHQ];
    NSLog(@"Distance to Apple HQ %4.0f km", distance);
    [appleHQ release];
}
```

just try this code ...
hope,this help you.